# Optional Group Capture with Lua Pattern Matching

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to parse chemical formulas in Lua using simple pattern matching. However, I do not know how to specify a capture group as being optional. Here is the pattern I have come up with:

```lua
pattern = "(%u%l*)(%d*)"
```

The first group captures the atomic symbol (i.e. "H", "He", etc..) and the second group captures the number of that atom in the molecule. This value is usually an integer value, but if it is 1, it is often omitted, such as in:

```lua
formula = "C2H6O"
```

When I attempt to do a global match, if there is no match the result of `count` is `''` instead of what I would anticipate of `nil`.

```lua
compound = {}
for atom,count in string.gmatch(formula, pattern) do
    compound[atom] = count or 1
end
```

Obviously I could just check if `count = ''`but I was curious if there was an optional capturing group in Lua.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> if there was an optional capturing group in Lua.

No; [pattern items](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) don't list captures as acceptable options, so you can't have, for example, `(%d*)?` like you'd do in Perl.

Comment: Thanks, great work on ZeroBrane BTW, it is what I am currently using :)

Comment: Thanks Moop for the feedback!

Answer (score 4):

There is no optional capturing group in Lua.

`count` is the empty string instead of nil because the empty string matches `%d*`.

Try this instead:

```
compound[atom] = tonumber(count) or 1
```

Note that `tonumber` will return nil if count is the empty string, which is what you want to check.

Comment: I don't get what you mean when it matches the empty string. Could you explain more on that? Wouldn't anything * match everything?

Comment: @Moop, `%d*` means *zero or more digits*.

Comment: @ihf Sure, but doesn't that mean it matches every "empty string"?

Comment: @Moop, `%d*` matches the empty string but does not have to end there; in fact, it matches the longest possible string of digits, or none, if there is none.