# Regex pattern issue in lua

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I have a URL string and need to get certain word from a match.

Example:

```
/school/student/studentname1/detail/55/address/address1
```

I am able to pass to fetch detail of the needed one like,

```
local s1,s2,s3 =myString:match("/school/student/(.-)/detail/(.-)/address/(.-)")
```

Now the problem is that my string can be

```
myString = /school/student/studentname1
```

or

```
myString = /school/student/studentname1/detail/55
```

In that case my regex is failing, any help ?

Comment: It looks like sometimes there can be no `detail`s nor `address`es, what do you want to happen then?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am trying to make regex in such a way that it matches all the condition (ie match all 3 values or match only 2 values or match only 1 value) and if matches detail or address then s2 and s3 will have value if not s2 and s3 will not have value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local all_fields = { student = 1, detail = 2, address = 3 }

local function parse(str)
   local info = {}
   local index
   for w in str:gmatch"/([^/]+)" do
      if index then
         info[index] = w
         index = nil
      else
         index = all_fields[w]
      end
   end
   return (table.unpack or unpack)(info, 1, 3)
end

local myString = '/school/student/studentname1/detail/55/address/address1'
local s1, s2, s3 = parse(myString)
print(s1, s2, s3)

myString = '/school/student/studentname1/address/address1'
s1, s2, s3 = parse(myString)
print(s1, s2, s3)

myString = '/school/student/studentname1/detail/55'
s1, s2, s3 = parse(myString)
print(s1, s2, s3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best one-liner I could come up with:

```
local s1,s2,s3 =myString:match("/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?[^/]*/?([^/]*)/?[^/]*/?([^/]*)")
```

#### [Demo](https://ideone.com/TsZaqi)

Explanation:

I use negated character classes to get the text between slashes in a generic way. This makes it easier to flag the later parts as optional using `*` for classes and `?` for slashes (you can make the initial part less generic and just use `/school/student/`).

This would be easy using (PC)RE, however, Lua Patterns do not support [optional capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044905/optional-group-capture-with-lua-pattern-matching) as well as [alternations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438358/what-is-the-alternation-operator-in-lua-patterns). Instead, you can use PCRE patterns in Lua with the [rex_pcre library](http://rrthomas.github.io/lrexlib/) or use the pattern-matching library [Lpeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html).

Comment: While It is a clever solution, it cannot distinguish between the exact `/school/student/...` and any other string with slashes, AFAIK. Not important if OP just works with `/school/student/...`, although.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, your original patter was not working as expected since it did not capture the address (because you used `.-` which is not greedy)

So one way to fix the original patter could be using `/school/student/([^/]+)/detail/([^/]+)/address/([^/]+)`

where `[^/]` means any character except `/`

Then, in order to optionally match some options and since lua patterns does not allow optional groups, you may need to use several steps like this:

```
myString = "/school/student/studentname1/detail/55"
local s1,s2,s3
s1 =myString:match("/school/student/([^/]+)")
if (s1 ~= nil) then
  print(s1)
  s2 =myString:match("/detail/([^/]+)")
  if (s2 ~= nil) then
    print(s2)
    s3 =myString:match("/address/([^/]+)")
    if (s3 ~= nil) then
      print(s3)
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, if you want to make sure that detail and address appear exactly on that order, you may use this:

```
myString = "/school/student/studentname1/address/myaddress"
local s1,s2,s3
s1 =myString:match("/school/student/([^/]+)")
if (s1 ~= nil) then
  print(s1)
  s1,s2 =myString:match("/school/student/([^/]+)/detail/([^/]+)")
  if (s2 ~= nil) then
    print(s2)
    s1,s2,s3 =myString:match("/school/student/([^/]+)/detail/([^/]+)/address/([^/]+)")
    if (s3 ~= nil) then
      print(s3)
    end
  end
end
```

That way it will find `/school/student/studentname1/detail/55` but it will not find `/school/student/studentname1/address/myaddress`. If you don't need it like this, just use the first version.